# Failure running tests using both hardhat in a foundry project

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, test, foundry

I want to run upgradeability test using `hardhat` in a foundry project.

Following is my project directory details:

```
❯ tree -L 1 -a
.
├── .env
├── .env.example
├── .eslintignore
├── .eslintrc.js
├── .gas-snapshot
├── .git
├── .github
├── .gitignore
├── .gitmodules
├── .npmignore
├── .nvmrc
├── .openzeppelin
├── .prettierignore
├── .prettierrc.json
├── .solcover.js
├── .solhint.json
├── .solhintignore
├── README.md
├── build
├── cache
├── cache_hardhat
├── deployment
├── foundry.toml
├── hardhat.config.ts
├── helper
├── lib
├── node_modules
├── out
├── package.json
├── remappings.txt
├── script
├── src
├── test
├── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

I have a file inside `test/perp/` - `upgrade.t.ts` with standard imports & codes.

I am getting nothing when I run test:

```
❯ npx hardhat test  

Compiled 41 Solidity files successfully
·------------------------|---------------------------|-------------|-----------------------------·
|  Solc version: 0.8.13  ·  Optimizer enabled: true  ·  Runs: 200  ·  Block limit: 30000000 gas  │
·························|···························|·············|······························
|  Methods                                                                                       │
··············|··········|·············|·············|·············|·············|················
|  Contract   ·  Method  ·  Min        ·  Max        ·  Avg        ·  # calls    ·  usd (avg)    │
·-------------|----------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|---------------·

  0 passing (168ms)
```

Comment: Please share the test code. Can't see whats wrong without it and also mention the path and file name when running the test. For example, npx hardhat test test/prep/xyz.ts

Comment: Well, it's a huge codebase in private mode. But I tried this `npx hardhat test test/perp/upgrade.t.ts`. Doesn't give anything.